# My attempt at FizzBuzz (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, fizzbuzz

Is this a good solution for FizzBuzz? What can I do better?

```
for num in range(1, 101):
    if num % 3 == 0:
        if num % 5 == 0:
            print("FizzBuzz")
        else:
            print("Fizz")
    elif num % 5 == 0:
        print("Buzz")
    else:
        print(num)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a good attempt, it reads easily and I like that you nested the `FizzBuzz` check within `Fizz` branch.

This doesn't look like most of the code you see in the wild, though, so a good exercise would be to extract a function for the FizzBuzz logic that is independent from the loop over numbers.

```
def get_fizzbuzz(num:int) -> str:
    result = ""
    # fizzbuzz logic
    if num % 3 == 0:
        if num % 5 == 0:
            result = "FizzBuzz"
        # ...
    return result
```

You could even make it more flexible by optionally allowing different numbers to be entered instead of 3 and 5, while still using 3 and 5 as default values, like so:

```
 def get_fizzbuzz(num:int, fizz:int = 3, buzz:int = 5) -> str:
    result = ""
    # fizzbuzz logic
    if num % fizz == 0:
        if num % buzz == 0:
            result = "FizzBuzz"
        # ...
    return result
```

Then you can just call the function in a loop using the default values:

```
for num in range(1, 101):
    print(get_fizzbuzz(num))
```

Or alternatively with different values for `fizz` and `buzz`:

```
for num in range(1, 101):
    print(get_fizzbuzz(num, 5, 7))
```

That will help you make your code more modular.

Note that I used Python 3's [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) in the function definition, which are completely optional but can make the code more clear, as well as provide [static code analysis](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-3-type-hints-and-static-analysis--cms-25731) with certain tools.

Answer (score 2):

The `True` and `False` of Python evaluates to `1` and `0` respectively. In Python, if you multiply a str with a number, you'll get that many str, so `2*'fizz'` would be, "fizzfizz". `0*"fizz"` would yield `''`.

---

With that in mind, this

```
if num % 3 == 0:
    if num % 5 == 0:
        print("FizzBuzz")
    else:
        print("Fizz")
elif num % 5 == 0:
    print("Buzz")
```

could be re written as:

```
print("fizz"*(num % 3 == 0)+"buzz"*(num % 5 == 0))
```

but now we need to do something with the printing of the ints.

---

Python provides an operator here: `or`. It is mainly used in `if` statements, but can also be used in-line:

```
variable = False or 2
>>> variable = 2
```

and:

```
variable = True or 2
>>> variable = True
```

so the printing of the ints is done by slapping `or num` on the expression:

```
print("fizz"*(num % 3 == 0)+"buzz"*(num % 5 == 0) or num)
```

since `''` evaluates to False in Python.

---

So your code could be rewritten as

```
for num in range(1, 101):
    print("fizz"*(num % 3 == 0)+"buzz"*(num % 5 == 0) or num)
```

with exactly the same logic as in your original code.

Comment: This is a nice/smart solution but it's just too hard to understand for such an easy task.

Comment: A perfect example of how a clever solution is not the same thing as a good solution.